# Pktgen returns Illegal instruction when trying to run

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, dpdk

I'm trying to setup Pktgen according to the [Getting started with Pktgen](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) guide in my VirtualBox which is running Ubuntu 22.04.1, Pktgen 22.04.01 and DPDK 22.11.1. But when I try to run pktgen I get an error message for "Illegal instruction".

When I run `sudo ./tools/run.py -s` I get the following sdk and target;

[image: result]

Here is my `default.cfg`

```
description = 'A Pktgen default simple configuration'

# Setup configuration
setup = {
'exec': (
'sudo', '-E'
    ),

'devices': (
    '00:08.0'
    ),
# UIO module type, igb_uio, vfio-pci or uio_pci_generic
'uio': 'uio_pci_generic'
}

# Run command and options
run = {
'exec': ('sudo', '-E'),

# Application name and use app_path to help locate the app
'app_name': 'pktgen',

# using (sdk) or (target) for specific variables
# add (app_name) of the application
# Each path is tested for the application
'app_path': (
    '/home/myname/Documents/Pktgen-DPDK/build/app/pktgen',
    ),

'cores': '3-4,5',
'nrank': '4',
'proc': 'auto',
'log': '7',
'prefix': 'pg',

'blocklist': (
    #'03:00.0', '05:00.0',
    #'81:00.0', '84:00.0'
    ),
'allowlist': (
     '00:08.0',
    ),

'opts': (
    '-v',
    '-T',
    '-P',
    ),
'map': (
    '[3:4].0',
    ),

'theme': 'themes/black-yellow.theme',
#'shared': '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-21.1'
}
```

Which runs this command:

```
sudo -E /home/myname/Documents/Pktgen-DPDK/build/app/pktgen -l 3-4,5 -n 4 --proc-type auto --log-level 7 --file-prefix pg -a 00:08.0 -- -v -T -P -m [3:4].0 -f themes/black-yellow.theme
```

This is the result:

```
Copyright(c) <2010-2021>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved. Powered by DPDK

Illegal instruction
```

### Update

After running `ninja -C build install`, "app/pktgen" was installed to "/usr/local/bin" and after running:

```
/usr/local/bin/pktgen -l 1,2,3 -n 4 -a 0000:00:08.0 -m 1024 -- -T -m [1:2].0
```

I still get "Illegal instruction" but now it also includes the message "(core dump")

```
Copyright(c) <2010-2021>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved. Powered by DPDK

Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have also set `enable-avx2` in `meson_options.txt` to `false`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is RTE_SDK set to as required by the documentation?

Comment: It seems the environment variables had disappeared, so when I run it now I get 
sdk '/home/myname/Documents/dpdk-stable-22.11.1', target 'x86_64-native-linux-gcc'. However I still get the illegal instruction error @stark

Comment: Illegal instruction typically means built for the wrong architecture. make clean and start over.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. I still get "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"  @stark

Comment: ninja is aptly named: silent, creates havoc, and disappears. Give me makefiles any day.